# Can i exchange two different cell data in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, compare, cell

i got two dataframes in R. And i want to compare two dataframe and change the cell data.

| data1 |
| --- |
| a |
| b |

| data11 | data21 |
| --- | --- |
| c | 1 |
| a | 2 |

if i compare [data1] and [data11], if "a" is exist in range [data11], then i change the "a" to "2" which is same row in data21.

Comment: Please share your sample data using dput(). And do you mean dataframe2 column1 (data11)? And what do you mean with the range of data11? And should the cell contain "c" or should it be equal to "c"? Generally your problem is hard to understand.

Comment: sry its first time to ask questions on here so i got some mistakes. i edit this question by make a table for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are working with two dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c("a", "b"))
df1
#>   col1
#> 1    a
#> 2    b

df2 <- data.frame(data11 = c("c", "a"), data21 = c(1, 2))
df2
#>   data11 data21
#> 1      c      1
#> 2      a      2
```

If you use `ifelse()`, the indexing might be incorrect (we would expect the results to be `"2" "b"` here):

```
ifelse(df1$col1 %in% df2$data11, df2$data21, df1$col1)
#> [1] "1" "b"
```

So you can use `merge()` instead:

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = "col1", by.y = "data11", all.x = TRUE)
df3$data21 <- ifelse(is.na(df3$data21), df3$col1, df3$data21)
df3
#>   col1 data21
#> 1    a      2
#> 2    b      b
```